# how to use CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC?

Tags: c++, c, opencv

It seems simple but I couldn't get it to work. I want to print out the format of an image by using

```
cvGetCaptureProperty(image, CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC)
```

where `image` is an object of CvCapture struct. 
This function returns `double`. I did convert it to char* so that I can print out the format but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get a `double*` and convert that:

```
double f = cvGetCaptureProperty(image, CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC);
char* fourcc = (char*) (&f); // reinterpret_cast
```

However, [this OpenCV highgui tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-write/video-write.html) suggests the following with the C++ interface:

```
int ex = static_cast<int>(inputVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC));

// Transform from int to char via Bitwise operators
char EXT[] = {(char)(ex & 0XFF),(char)((ex & 0XFF00) >> 8),(char)((ex & 0XFF0000) >> 16),(char)((ex & 0XFF000000) >> 24),0};
```

Of course, instead of the `get` method, you'd use `cvGetCaptureProperty`.

Comment: I did that but I got nothing. `double f = cvGetCaptureProperty(image, CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC);
    char* fourcc = (char*)(&f); 
    std::cout << "\nFormat               : " << fourcc[0] << fourcc[1] <<  std::endl;` I got nothing.

Comment: @CroCo Huh, well you could follow the example of the highgui tutorial (see update) and cast the double to int, and transform to char with a series of bitwise operations.

Comment: @CroCo Also you could try `cout << "format: " << EXT << endl;` with the null-terminated version created by all the bitwise ops.

Comment: But why do I need to use bitwise? Is there a straightforward method to do that? Also, I've tried to used the method in openCV's documentation however If I do access to `EXT[5]`, it gives me data. Why this happens? Doesn't it have only four characters?

Comment: @CroCo A C string is [null-terminated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string), meaning the last byte is `'\0'`. Don't access it directly, as it just signals the end of a "string". (Ignore it, as it is just used so that `cout` [knows when to stop](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/66-c-style-strings/).)

Comment: I know that but what I'm getting is real data not just garbage. Why this happens?

Comment: Because indexing starts with 0. The 1st element in `EXT` is `EXT[0]`, 5th element in `EXT` is `EXT[4]`. `EXT[5]` is out of the array. I don't know what you mean by real data vs. garbage however.

Comment: I know EXT[5] is out of the range but I tried to access to it, I got a character. I was expecting to get a garbage value.

Comment: @CroCo Why access it?  It could be any junk in memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function:

```
// http://mkonrad.net/2014/06/24/cvvideocamera-vs-native-ios-camera-apis.html
void fourCCStringFromCode(int code, char fourCC[5]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        fourCC[3 - i] = code >> (i * 8);
    }
    fourCC[4] = '\0';
}
```

For instance:

```
    double f = cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC);
    printf("fourcc=%d\n", f); // outputs fourcc=6
    char fourcc[5];
    fourCCStringFromCode((int)f, fourcc);
    printf("fourcc=%s\n", fourcc); // outputs fourcc=DIVX
```